# Truffle test error: setter does not works

Tags: testrpc, testing, truffle-contract, truffle-migration

I have very basic contract like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Playground {
    uint public tokenPrice = 1;

    function setTokenPrice(uint newTokenPrice) public returns (uint) {
        tokenPrice = newTokenPrice;

        return tokenPrice;
    }
}
```

and correspondig test:

```
  it("should have token price changeable and publicly visible", () => {
    let instance;

    return Playground.deployed().then(inst => {
      instance = inst;
      return instance.tokenPrice.call();
    }).then(price => {
      console.log('Initial price:' + formatNumber(price));
      return instance.setTokenPrice.call(2);
    }).then(price => {
      console.log('Price immediately after change:' + formatNumber(price));
      return instance.tokenPrice.call();
    }).then(price => {
      console.log('Price after get:' + formatNumber(price));
      assert.equal(price, 2, format(price, 2, "Token Price"));
    });
  });
```

This test checks initial value of token price then change it and check again. But it seems that setter does not work! Here is the output:

```
Initial price:1
Price immediately after change:2
Price after get:1
```

I.e. value that updated in setter returned correctly but when I am getting it again - it returns old, not updated value. What is wrong here?

Tests are running in local `testrpc` instance. In Remix data updated as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling setTokenPrice func with a .call() on a function that intends to write on the Blockchain. 
call() methods are used when you want to read data from the contract.